# PHP unintentially stripping newlines from MySql TEXT

Tags: php, mysql

I have a TEXT column within my MySql database with the content of:

```
test\r\n\r\ntesting\r\n\r\ntested
```

however...

when I refer to the content within the column...

```
$queryTHREAD = "SELECT * FROM FusionNotes ORDER BY 'When'";
$resultTHREAD = mysqli_query($db, $queryTHREAD); 
$rowsTHREAD = mysqli_num_rows($resultTHREAD);
while ($rowTHREAD = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultTHREAD)) {
    $test = $rowTHREAD['What'];
    echo($test);
```

It returns:

```
testtestingtested
```

I want to retain the `\r\n` however I have no idea why it's stripping.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you print the results as part of the html code? Because in html new line characters are not interpreted as new line (unless in a textbox or <pre> tag), you need <br> tags instead. Use nl2br() to replace line breaks in your text with <br> tags.

Comment: I am using str_replace("\\r\\n\\r\\n","<br/>",$rowTHREAD['What']) which works fine as long as I have the new lines in there

Comment: Why do you reinvent the wheel?

Comment: nl2br() is more efficient howver the issue is php not returning the new lines to begin with.

Comment: If the new line characters are stored within the database, then php does return them. You may not seem them when the webpage is rendered, but they should be there. If php does not retrieve them from the database, then they had been stripped from the text **before** text was stored in the  database.

Comment: There is nothing else in the code to strip them however it IS in the database as shown below: `FusionNotes` (`Who`, `WhosBusiness`, `When`, `What`) VALUES
('Ryan', '1', '2015-11-26 16:34:38', 'test\r\n\r\ntesting\r\n\r\ntested');

Comment: Then they will be there when php fetches the field.